# Spring boot upgrade 1.4.1 to 1.5.4 failure - build path incomplete

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Using STS 3.9.0.RELEASE

I have a project that was at Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE. Editing the pom.xml to change this to 1.5.4 fails miserably.

First I had to delete .m2/repository for maven since it was refusing to find the new required versions of jar files. This means there is a serious problem with maven.

Second, the build keeps failing, first asking me to correct the build path because it couldn't find ServletException, then after messing with pom.xml it is now saying "The type org.springrramework.context.annotation.ComponentScan" cannot be resolved.

I have forced maven updates and cleaned the project.

Internet articles on upgrading always talk about deprecations and items removed, never the exact mechanics of performing the upgrade.

Does anyone have any insight on how to correctly perform this upgrade?

I had similar problems a few months ago with an earlier 1.5 upgrade and gave up. The project was working fine before the upgrade attempt.

I found one article that suggested explicitly adding the servlet api to pom.xml, but this made no noticeable difference.

Exiting and restarting makes the error mention missing ServletException again, indirectly referenced from a required class file.

I get similar errors when trying to create a new spring boot starter project.

Comment: Are the jar files that Maven is downloading corrupted? It sounds like they might be. You could check by trying to list their contents with `unzip -l`. If they are, that would point to a possible problem with your network, proxy server, Maven repository, etc